# Spring 3 Controller's private variable of type List empties. Session timeout?

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, controller, portlet

I have a portlet controller that has two list variables

```
private List<MyObject1DTO> list1;
private List<MyObject2DTO> list2;
```

In my JSP I use AJAX requests to send objects back to the controller that adds the object
to either list depending what the user submitted. What happens to these lists when the user session timeouts?

On occasion when the user is done adding objects to those lists (It's a big form) and has
filled the rest of the form and presses submit the validation of those lists (they cannot be empty) fails. I'm wondering if the session timeouts somehow when the user is filling the form and it clears those lists. What else could cause the lists to empty?

Is the way I've done this a design flaw? Is there a better way of doing this?

It is a really big form and there's a lot of fields. There are two different parts in the form that creates those objects and sends them to the lists by AJAX request. When I'm handling the ajax request in the controller I do not have access to the model itself so that I could add the objects to the model. So I did it with lists in the controller.

Edit:

```
@Controller("myController")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MyController {
  private List<MyObject1DTO> list1;
  private List<MyObject2DTO> list2;    
  @ModelAttribute(value = "myFormDTO")
  public MyFormDTO getMyFormDTO() {
  ....
  }
  // Controller mappings etc.
}
```

I have an object bound as model attribute that represents my form. But this does not include
those lists. Because I do not know a way (don't think it is possible) to access this model attribute in my ajax request that I use to add objects to the lists. Basically the form the users sees is fields that are bound to the model attribute. Then there are two different "baskets" (lists) that the user can add items to (The lists in the controller hold the objects added by the user). The way I've done the adding of the items into the basket is by an ajax request.

Comment: are these lists part of a form backing bean? and is this bean stored in the session? can you provide some code of your Controller?

Comment: Did the additional information help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you take a look at Spring Webflow or you set the model attribute as session attribue.

you can annotate your class as follows

```
@Controller("myController")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
@SessionAttributes("myFormDTO")
public class MyController {
    ....
}
```

spring will add your model attribute to the session, from this it follows that you can access your model attribute in your controller methods.

```
@RequestMapping("/ajax/addToList1")
public void ajaxAddToList1(@ModelAttribute("myFormDTO") MyFormDTO form, ....) {
    form.getList1().add(.....);
}
```

don't use Controller member variables (unless you use @Scope annotation) since Spring Controllers are singletons per default and concurrent users might interfere which each other.

Comment: Thank you SO much! I feel like such a total dummy for not thinking about concurrent users interfering with each other. Another question: Is there anyway to remove the myFormDTO from SessionAttributes other than using SessionStatus.complete() ? I cannot seem to be able to remove it. I mean if the user does not complete the form (Leaves page) and then comes back then the fields he filled before are filled with that data (When the user has clicked submit once or interacted with the form atleast once).

Comment: Let me clarify a bit more: When the user comes to the page it is handled by my "default" method. It has the myFormDTO annotated with @ModelAttribute. As it is found in the SessionAttributes it is not recreated.

Comment: you can create the model attribute manually. i guess you have at least a GET method that renders the form only and a POST method that handles form submission. in the GET method you can always put a newly created model in the session by yourself: model.addAttribute("myFormDTO",new MyFormDTO); Spring will put it in the session automatically

Comment: Ah Sorry. Found the button. :) First time writing here. Indeed I just figured it out the way you said, adding a new model attribute manually in my render method. Thank You very much for the help.